# How to find integral $\underbrace{\int\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{2+x}}}}}_{n}dx,x>-2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

Find the integral
$$\int\underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{2+x}}}}}_{n}dx,x>-2$$

where $n$ define  the number of  the square

I know  this  if 
$0 \le x\le 2$, then let $$x=2\cos{t},0\le t\le\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$
so
$$\sqrt{2+x}=\sqrt{2+2\cos{t}}=2\cos{\dfrac{t}{2}}$$
so
$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+x}}=2\cos{\dfrac{t}{2^2}}$$
so
$$\int\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots+\sqrt{2+x}}}}dx=\int2\cos{\dfrac{t}{2^n}}(-2\sin{t})dt$$

and for $x\ge 2$ case, I  let
$x=\cosh{t}$, but for  $-2\le x\le 0$ case, I can't do it.

Comment: How many iterations of $\sqrt{2+\ldots}$ are there? Is that your $n$ variable?

Comment: @user2357112,yes,that's mean

Comment: Can't you still take $x=2\cos t$ but with different values of $t$?  If you take $t$ from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ then $\cos(t/2)$ is still positive so there is no problem with the square root.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you are concerned about domain issues, just let $t \in [0, \pi]$ (not only $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$) so that $-2 \le 2 \cos t \le 2$.

Comment: @SammyBlack yes indeed.  Do you agree that it is, essentially, just the same as what the OP has done?  I'm still not quite sure if I might have missed something.

Answer (score 5):

You were too timid: For $-2\leq x\leq2$ use the substitution
$$x=2\cos t\qquad(-\pi\leq t\leq 0)\ .$$
Then everything goes through as before:
$$\sqrt{2+x}=\sqrt{2+2\cos t}=2\cos{t\over2},\quad \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+x}}=\sqrt{2+\cos{t\over2}}=2\cos{t\over4}\ ,$$
etcetera.

Answer (score 3):

For the finitely many nested radical case,
$$-4\int \cos\left(\frac{t}{2^n}\right)\sin t\,dt=-2\int \left(\sin(2^{-n}t+t)-\sin(2^{-n}t-t)\right)\,dt$$
$$=-2\left(-\frac{\cos(t(2^{-n}+1))}{2^{-n}+1}+\frac{\cos(t(2^{-n}-1))}{2^{-n}-1}\right)+C$$

Substitute $t=\arccos(x/2)$ to obtain the answer.

The substitution is valid for $-2\le x\le 2$.

I hope this addresses the issue.

Comment: This seems to be an extension of the OP's work for the $0 \le x \le 2$ case, but the OP is looking for an approach that works for $-2 \le x \le 0$. He's not trying to finish the $0 \le x \le 2$ case; he's probably already done that.

Comment: @user2357112: Yes, sorry, I didn't understand it properly. But for $-2\le x\le 0$, I think we can do the same thing, right?

Comment: I think we can, but this answer makes no attempt to point that out. The integral computations do little to answer the question; the important information is that the approach the OP was already using also works for this case.

Comment: @user2357112: Now its unclear to me what OP is actually asking. Should I add the integral computations for both the cases i.e for $-2\le x \le 2$ and for $x>2$?

Comment: I don't think the integral computations are particularly important at all, but you should probably mention something about this working for $x < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong approach, take a look at this

$$f(x) = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...+\sqrt{2+x}}}   $$

Square both sides

$$(f(x))^2 = 2+\sqrt{2+...+\sqrt{2+x}}   $$

$$(f(x))^2 = 2+f(x) $$

$$(f(x))^2 -f(x)-2= 0 $$

This has two solutions $f(x)=2$ and $f(x)=-1$

Note that $f(x)$ cannot be -1, since square root is always positive for real numbers, and it is given that $x > -2$

Hence you have $f(x)=2$, which is independent of $x$

The answer is therefore finally 2x

Comment: if $x\to\infty$,then $f(x)\to  ？$

Comment: @user155188 You have the right functional equation but the wrong roots. The positive root is $2$.

Comment: The question is asking about **finitely many** nested radicals.